# How to correctly use Query Builder Laravel in my situation?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have a part of the SQL-code that needs to be converted correctly for Query Builder (Laravel).

```
select
p.*
from posts p, comments c
where c.post_id = p.post_id
group by p.post_id
order by avg(c.mark_first) desc
```

Can anyone halp me? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using query builder you could write it as

```
$posts = DB::table('posts as p')
            ->join('comments as c', 'p.post_id', '=', 'c.post_id')
            ->groupBy('p.post_id')
            ->orderByRaw('avg(c.mark_first) desc')
            ->select('p.*')
            ->get();
```

Its better if you could add all the columns in `groupby` which you want in `select` part because above query will become invalid if mysql's `full_group_by` mode is enabled which is enabled by default in 5.7+